# How to get python list first element id

Tags: python

I have a list

```
MENU_Items = [ {  "ID":0x3B08, "Description":"Read Levelling Status\t\t"},    
                { "ID":0x3B39, "Description":"Read Air system control module state"},
                { "ID":0x3B3A, "Description":"Read Movement inhibit state\t"},     
                { "ID":0x3B3B, "Description":"Read Target height status\t\t"}]
```

Input = 1

MENU_Items[Input - 1]

I am getting the result as below:

```
{'ID': 15112, 'Description': 'Read Levelling Status\t\t'}
```

I want to extract only 'ID' as a output

```
I am trying something like this MENU_Items[Input - 1].ID
```

Its not working.

Comment: What about `MENU_Items[Input-1]['ID']`?

Comment: Sometimes I wish there was still the minimal understanding WTF you are doing closing reason.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Its working fine now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MENU_Items[Input - 1]` will you first element of array  first element which is a object. `['ID']` instead of `.ID` will give you id of that object

So, use `MENU_Items[Input - 1]['ID']`

Answer (score 0):

So why not do something like this:

```
MENU_Items = [ {  "ID":0x3B08, "Description":"Read Levelling Status\t\t"},
            { "ID":0x3B39, "Description":"Read Air system control module state"},
            { "ID":0x3B3A, "Description":"Read Movement inhibit state\t"},
            { "ID":0x3B3B, "Description":"Read Target height status\t\t"}]

print(MENU_Items[0]["ID"])
```

The output would be

```
15112
```

To do this with user input, you can simply do:

```
info = int(input("Please enter which ID you wish to access: "))

x = info - 1

print(MENU_Items[x]["ID"])
```

Your output would be determined based on what they selected. I really wouldn't go this route though as there is no error handling, and you are not guaranteed they are entering an int which will cause an error as well. I'm just showing you a down and dirty quick example of how it could be done.

Answer (score 0):

```
 >>> MENU_Items = [ {  "ID":0x3B08, "Description":"Read Levelling Status\t\t"},    
...                 { "ID":0x3B39, "Description":"Read Air system control module state"},
...                 { "ID":0x3B3A, "Description":"Read Movement inhibit state\t"},     
...                 { "ID":0x3B3B, "Description":"Read Target height status\t\t"}]
```

> for input  = 1,search for index = 0

```
>>> MENU_Items[0]
{'ID': 15112, 'Description': 'Read Levelling Status\t\t'}
>>> MENU_Items[0]['ID']
15112
```